# Can anyone find out what's wrong in this code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

Can anyone find out what's wrong with this code? I copy-pasted from a book.

```
def findSmallestNumber(arr):
    smallestNumber = arr[0]
    for i in range(1,len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < smallestNumber:
            smallestNumber = arr[i]
    return smallestNumber

def sort(arr):
    newArr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        smallestNumber = findSmallestNumber(arr)
        newArr.append(arr.pop(smallestNumber))
    return newArr
    

print (sort([12,32,4,22,6]))
```

I get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
File "<string>", line 12, in sort
```

Comment: Are you sure that output isn't followed by an error message?

Comment: IndexError: pop index out of range

Comment: `findSmallestNumber` returns the smallest *value* from your list. You're passing that to `pop`. But `pop` expects an *index*.

Comment: `findSmallestNumber` returns a *value* from the array. If you then treat that value like an *index*, there's absolutely no guarantee that'll do anything useful.

Comment: As a beginner you should *not* be investing time in learning Python 2. Those of us who still work in it do so because we have to support or migrate legacy code. It is not something you should be doing by choice. Please download Python 3.9 and learn that instead. If you work in Linux, *don't* attempt to upgrade your existing version. Python 3 will happily live side-by-side with whatever ancient version of Python your distro requires.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def sort(arr):
    newArr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        smallestNumber = findSmallestNumber(arr)
        newArr.append(arr[arr.index(smallestNumber)])
        arr.remove(smallestNumber)
    return newArr
```

Answer (score 0):

The pop() method need not value of element, but index of that element.
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/array.html#array.ArrayType.pop

Note that the array elements don't even have to be numbers.

Try this: print(sort(["Dog", "Bird", "Cat", "Cow", "Horse"]))

Correct:

```
def findIndexOfSmallestValue(arr):
    smallestValueIdx = 0
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < arr[smallestValueIdx]:
            smallestValueIdx = i
    return smallestValueIdx


def sort(arr):
    newArr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        idx = findIndexOfSmallestValue(arr)
        newArr.append(arr.pop(idx))
    return newArr
```